Explicit Construction of the Alternating Subgroup of a Coxeter Group
Given a Coxeter group $(W,S)$ with $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$, I want to show that the alternating subgroup $H$ (containing all elements with even length w.r.t. $S$) is generated by $\{s_is_n\}_{i=1}^{n-1}$.
If we pick any element $w\in H$, we can expressed  $w=s_{\alpha_1}\cdots s_{\alpha_{2k}}$ for some $k=0,1,\dots$  with $l(w)=2k$
But then I have no idea how to "insert" those $s_n$ in between. I have tried using the order,
i.e. $\left(s_{\alpha_i}s_n\right)^{m(s_{\alpha_i},s_n)}=e\implies s_{\alpha_i}=s_n\left(s_{\alpha_i},s_n\right)^{m(s_{\alpha_i}s_n)-1}$
But I don't know how to deal with the $s_n$ in front, and I can't even handle the cases where $m(s_{\alpha_i},s_n)=\infty$.
Any help is much appreciated!

Remember that the generating elements are all involutions. For all $i,j<n$ we see that
$$
s_is_j=(s_is_n)(s_n^{-1}s_j)=(s_is_n)(s_n^{-1}s_j^{-1})=(s_is_n)(s_js_n)^{-1}
$$
is an element of the subgroup $H$. The claim follows from this.

Thank you very much!!!
